# Making the game Checkers in python with pygame but are running into minor logical errors

Tags: python, pygame

The problem is when this valid moves function runs and goes through the 2 tuples it only ever appends the second tuple when both of the tuples should be appended as valid moves.

For example the first move on the board, both (1, 1) and (-1, 1) should be allowed but only (-1, 1) is allowed always vice versa for the other player the coordinates are just different( (-1, -1) and (1, -1) ).

In checkers if there is a opponent piece on your diagonal you can jump over it diagonally and take it. This works fine but again only for the second tuple. Ive stepped through it in the debugger and it just passes by the the first tuple. I don't know why this may be and I've been stuck for days. The board is a big list with 8 more lists for rows. Just to clarify the problem is in this method since the piece can move (1,1) but never
(-1, 1)

The get mouse pos simply iterates through the list and checks if a move is allowed. The get turn function just changes the turn accordingly.

The last bit is from the main file, its the only thing I link to the problem but in the debugger it seems theres something wrong with the valid_moves functions.

```
self.directions_1 = [(-1, -1), (1, - 1)]

    def valid_moves(self, start_x, start_y):
        """
        Find all of the valid moves for a selected piece and append them to a list
        """
        start_column = int(start_x // SQUARESIZE)
        start_row = int(start_y // SQUARESIZE)
        if self.turn == player2:
            for d in self.directions_1:
                x, y = d
                self.white_valid_moves.clear()
                if self.board[start_row + x][start_column + y] == 0:
                    self.white_valid_moves.append((x, y))
                if self.board[start_row + x][start_column + y] == player1:
                    if x == -1 and y == -1:
                        self.white_valid_moves.append((x - 1, x - 1))
                        self.board[start_row + x][start_column + y] = 0

                    if x == 1 and y == -1:
                        self.white_valid_moves.append((x + 1, y - 1))
                        self.board[start_row + x][start_column + y] = 0  

    def get_mouse_pos_and_place(self, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y):
        """
        Takes care of placing a piece and iterating through the valid moves lists
        """
        start_column = int(start_x // SQUARESIZE)
        start_row = int(start_y // SQUARESIZE)
        end_column = int(end_x // SQUARESIZE)
        end_row = int(end_y // SQUARESIZE)
        if (self.board[start_row][start_column]) in (player1, player2):
            if self.turn == player1:
                for x, y in self.red_valid_moves:
                    print(self.red_valid_moves)
                    if (x == start_column - end_column) and (y == start_row - end_row):
                        self.board[start_row][start_column] = 0
                        self.board[end_row][end_column] = player1
            elif self.turn == player2:
                for x, y in self.white_valid_moves:
                    print(self.white_valid_moves)
                    if (x == start_column - end_column) and (y == start_row - end_row):
                        self.board[start_row][start_column] = 0
                        self.board[end_row][end_column] = player2
        self.get_turn()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            start_x = event.pos[0]
            start_y = event.pos[1]
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            end_x = event.pos[0]
            end_y = event.pos[1]

            board.valid_moves(start_x, start_y)
            board.get_mouse_pos_and_place(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y)
            board.print_board()
            board.draw_board(screen)
            board.draw_checkers(screen)
```

Comment: Hello, could you please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order that we can test several things.

Comment: I put it outside same issue

Comment: And I don't really know how to make a minimal reproducible example but in the debugger it just skips the first tuple even though its equal to 1

Comment: Just think that the problem has to be in this set of code and if u cant find a solution can u tell me a way in which I can rather that the debugger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227410/discussion-between-coding-and-rabbid76).

Comment: I added a little bit of code that I think could relate could you check over it the info about it is in the answer

Comment: This is for the jumping over if there is a opposing piece there then we append a move accordingly

Comment: One of the moves will be (2,2) and the other (-2,2)

Comment: The for loop has 2 different tuples so once x and y will be 1 and 1 the other time - 1 and 1

Comment: Ive changed it. My bad this is how it is in the actual code it was just a error

Comment: `self.white_valid_moves.clear()` is still in the `for`-loop

Comment: There is a typo `self.white_valid_moves.append((x - 1, x - 1))` needs to be `self.white_valid_moves.append((x - 1, y - 1))`

Comment: OK thank you can you look at the main game loop and do you know how to make it so it isn't a drag mechanism but rather 2 mouse clicks because I don't know how to.

Comment: @Coding I've answered your question. *" do you know how to make it so it isn't a drag mechanism but rather 2 mouse clicks"* - Is a new question -> [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend simplifying your code. The player's movement can be calculated by multiplying `x` and `y` by two.
Do not remove the opponent's piece when evaluating possible moves. It's too early and it removes all opponents along possible moves:

```py
def valid_moves(self, start_x, start_y):
    """
    Find all of the valid moves for a selected piece and append them to a list
    """
    start_column = int(start_x // SQUARESIZE)
    start_row = int(start_y // SQUARESIZE)
    if self.turn == player2:

        self.white_valid_moves.clear()
        for d in self.directions_1:
            x, y = d
            
            if self.board[start_row + x][start_column + y] == 0:
                self.white_valid_moves.append((x, y))
            
            elif self.board[start_row + x][start_column + y] == player1:
                self.white_valid_moves.append((x*2, y*2))
```

You must remove the opponent when the player is moved:

```py
def get_mouse_pos_and_place(self, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y):
    """
    Takes care of placing a piece and iterating through the valid moves lists
    """
    start_column = int(start_x // SQUARESIZE)
    start_row = int(start_y // SQUARESIZE)
    end_column = int(end_x // SQUARESIZE)
    end_row = int(end_y // SQUARESIZE)
    
    if (self.board[start_row][start_column]) in (player1, player2):

        if self.turn == player1:
            valid_moves = self.red_valid_moves
        else
            valid_moves = self.white_valid_moves
        
        dx = end_column - start_column
        dy = end_row - start_row
        
        if (dx, dy) in valid_moves: 
            self.board[start_row][start_column] = 0
            self.board[start_row + dx//2][start_column + dy//2] = 0
            self.board[end_row][end_column] = self.turn

    self.get_turn()

    # [...]
```

Comment: It works thank you can you explain the error is it because I was removing pieces in the valid moves function

Comment: Nevermind the problem is the same as before now with the red pieces and the jumping over